# Copy specific characters from first two lines of text file to variables

Tags: bash, file, text, character

I have a few thousand text files that I need to rename.  I may need to do this from time to time so would like to create a bash script for this task.  The new file name should be created from some characters from the first line, and some from the second line.  An example of the content is :

```
Record #123987. More stuff .here
Something 'I need this string' blah blah
More lines of info
....
```

Can you help me copy the record number from line 1, and the text between single quotes from line 2 to variables so I can loop through the files and rename them using the variables.

The reason I am being specific about the line numbers is that there may be more information in single quotes, and more '#' and '.' elsewhere in the text.

Also, there may not always be the same amount of characters before and after the required information in each file so I cant just trim x number of characters.

Thanks

Comment: This is something that would best be written in Perl, or another higher-level language.  While you can use bash scripts to extract the lines, finding a string enclosed in quotes will be hard (can there be backslash-escaped quotes within the string?)

Comment: Thank you for looking at this.  I am not sure what you mean.  The string within the single quotes will contain alphabetical characters and spaces only.

Comment: Okay, what I meant was a string like this:  'Don\'t worry about apostrophes'

Comment: keep in mind that for large(r) numbers of files you'll likely see faster processing times if you limit the number of sub-processes you spawn (eg, process substitution, pipes) as well as limit the number of times you process each file

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on it.
Note that this will not work on line two if the quoted string may have escaped quotes within it. 
e.g. `'Don\'t worry about apostrophes'`

For that you'll need to use a small parser of some sort, and I'd recommend writing something in Perl if you want it to work easily in environments where bash is usually installed.

```sh
for file in "$@"; do
    record=$(sed -rn '1s/^Record[ \t]+#([0-9]+).*/\1/p' "$file")
    quoted=$(sed -rn "2s/^[^']+'([^']+).*/\1/p" "$file")
    echo $record $quoted
done
```

I'm using sed to replace all except the digits found after the hash on line 1.
Then I'm using the same technique to look for everything within the first set of quotes on line 2.

### The regular expressions

- /^Record[ \t]+#([0-9]+).*/

  Match the word "Record" at beginning of line, followed by one or more tabs or spaces, followed by hash, followed by one or more digits, then anything.  Extract the digits.
- /^[^']+'([^']+).*/

  Match one or more non-quote characters at beginning of line, then a single quote, then extract everything up to (but not including) the next quote.

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions:

- line 1 always has the desired data between the first set of hash (`#`) and period (`.`)
- line 2 always has the desired data between the first set of single quotes (`'`)
- we don't have to worry about any issues as mentioned by @LukeH in the comments (I'm not saying this shouldn't be considered, but it's a bit of overkill if the OP can confirm no funky stuff - control characters, escaped characters, etc - in the fields we're looking to parse)

One `awk` solution that pulls the desired data from the first 2 rows of a file:

```
awk -F"[#.']" '
NR<=2 { printf "%s ",$2 ; next }
NR>=3 { exit }
' <filename>
```

Where:

- `-F"[#.']"` - use 3 different delimiters (hash, period, single-quote)
- `NR<=2 ...` - for the first 2 lines of the file print field #2; use `printf` and no '\n' so that the 2 fields are printed on a single line
- `NR>=3 ...` - not interested in the rest of the file so `exit` processing

For the sample given:

```
$ cat record.dat
Record #123987. More stuff .here
Something 'I need this string' blah blah
More lines of info
....

$  awk -F"[#.']" 'NR<= 2 { printf "%s ",$2 ; next } NR>=3 {exit} {print $0}' record.dat
123987 I need this string
```

We can now feed these results into a `read` command to capture our 2 fields into 2 variables:

```
$ read -r a b < <(awk -F"[#.']" 'NR<= 2 { printf "%s ",$2 ; next } NR>=3 {exit} {print $0}' record.dat)
```

And to show that the 2 variables have been properly populated:

```
$ echo ":$a:$b:"
:123987:I need this string:
```

Answer (score 2):

Pipe the output of this command to a shell:

```
$ awk '
    FNR==1 { recno=$2; gsub(/[^0-9]/,"",recno) }
    FNR==2 { sub(/[^\047]+\047/,""); sub(/\047.*/,""); gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"_");
             printf "mv -- \047%s\047 \047%s_%s\047\n", FILENAME, $0, recno
           }
' file
mv -- 'file' 'I_need_this_string_123987'
```

If you're using GNU awk you could add `nextfile` on a line of its own after the `print` for efficiency.

Comment: What's your thought on using the `system` command to facilitate the `mv`?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin It's unnecessarily spawning a shell per `mv` and using tthe awk script as a shell. Here's the commands if we use system(): `shell { awk { system { shell { mv } } } }` vs if we don't: `shell { awk; mv }`. When you see it hierarchically that way I think you can appreciate the simplicity of just having the shell calling `awk` and then calling `mv` using the awk output.

Comment: That's the thought process I was looking for, thank you! -- and also snapped to the fact you can't use `system (mv file)` while processing records from the file -- can you? Or does `awk` avoid that somehow?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin awk could move the file, I suspect because it's using a file descriptor once the file's been opened so the name no longer matters after that but idk for sure what the mechanics are.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Assumptions:
1. Record number is the first occurence of string between "#" and "." in line 1
2. Text is between the first set of single quotes in line 2 (and therefore will not handle apostrophes)

```
    $ cat > foo.txt
    Record #123987. More stuff .here
    Something 'I need this string' blah blah
    More lines of info
    ....

    $ cat > foo2.txt
    Record #987321. More stuff .here
    Something 'I need this string too' blah blah
    More lines of info
    ....

    $ for file in *.txt
    > do
    > var1=`sed -n 1p $file | awk -F "#" '{print $2}' | awk -F"." '{print $1}'`
    > var2=`sed -n 2p $file | awk -F "'" '{print $2}'`
    > echo "Variable1="$var1 " and Variable2="$var2
    > done
```

Output:

```
    Variable1=987321  and Variable2=I need this string too
    Variable1=123987  and Variable2=I need this string
```